# Operacion contar id's diferentes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

necesito hacer esta operacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Contar el total de cada cantidad de registros con un rrpp diferente: 1,2,3,4  ∞

Normalmente utilizo esto para sumar los registros de un RRPP:

```
  $variable = Modelo::where('dia_id' , $request->id)->where('rrpp' , 1)->count('id');
```

pero de esta forma solo obtengo el resultado de 1 en especifico.
Y lo que necesito es obtener el resultado de esta forma

```
$array = [10, 20,30,];
```

**para luego poder graficarlo**

necesito ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar `groupby()` y luego contar los elementos de cada grupo [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#grouping)

Ejemplo:

```
$coleccion = Modelo::groupBy('rrpp')
->selectRaw('count(*) as total, rrpp')
->get();
```

Comment: Funciona pero como puedo pasarlo en este formato a los resultados? $array = [10, 20,30,];

Comment: Agrega `->toArray()` después del `get()` eso va a convertir el resultado a `array`, si lo deseas en otro formato va a ser más fácil de manipular

Comment: @seonica, Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas